# How to parse json response from google drive API get files in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-drive-api

i got this response from curl to https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='[folder ID]'+in+parents&key=[token]

```
{ "kind": "drive#fileList", "etag": "\"sUwP36qaD260RUkBRZNiE0CB3Hg/9BIQNPy_h12YATGHr4uxbE86-kk\"", "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='1kbHKqYhX9ZjWjAjE-9viiZ7AsL5HJVIO'+in+parents", "incompleteSearch": false, "items": [ { "kind": "drive#file", "id": "19WK5HWnV0x2u0fDXugrisJRG7ZKOHOds", "etag": "\"sUwP36qaD260RUkBRZNiE0CB3Hg/MTUxMDIxMTQ2OTY2Mw\"", "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/19WK5HWnV0x2u0fDXugrisJRG7ZKOHOds", "webContentLink": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=19WK5HWnV0x2u0fDXugrisJRG7ZKOHOds&export=download", "alternateLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/19WK5HWnV0x2u0fDXugrisJRG7ZKOHOds/view?usp=drivesdk", "embedLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/19WK5HWnV0x2u0fDXugrisJRG7ZKOHOds/preview?usp=drivesdk", "iconLink": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/application/x-rar", "title": "Ab Du BD 720p.rar", "mimeType": "application/x-rar", "labels": { "starred": false, "hidden": false, "trashed": false, "restricted": false, "viewed": false }, "copyRequiresWriterPermission": false, "createdDate": "2017-11-09T07:10:47.865Z", "modifiedDate": "2017-11-09T07:11:09.663Z", "markedViewedByMeDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "version": "19", "parents": [ { "kind": "drive#parentReference", "id": "1kbHKqYhX9ZjWjAjE-9viiZ7AsL5HJVIO", "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/19WK5HWnV0x2u0fDXugrisJRG7ZKOHOds/parents/1kbHKqYhX9ZjWjAjE-9viiZ7AsL5HJVIO", "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1kbHKqYhX9ZjWjAjE-9viiZ7AsL5HJVIO", "isRoot": false } ], "downloadUrl": "https://doc-10-a4-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/o7l0aeqi0drljltr83c3565k9441n6of/1313an8qmrf0v4n7do9ppsqhpf45dmqk/1549094400000/05301767890081372214/13058876669334088843/19WK5HWnV0x2u0fDXugrisJRG7ZKOHOds?e=download&gd=true", "userPermission": { "kind": "drive#permission", "etag": "\"sUwP36qaD260RUkBRZNiE0CB3Hg/3cxCmsajfyZJPGtyQXwHveV8jkI\"", "id": "me", "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/19WK5HWnV0x2u0fDXugrisJRG7ZKOHOds/permissions/me", "role": "writer", "type": "user" }, "originalFilename": "Salinan [Drivenime] Ab Du BD 720p.rar", "fileExtension": "rar", "md5Checksum": "62504a3df8228c3c573af2c4d48d2499", "fileSize": "3193962228", "quotaBytesUsed": "0", "ownerNames": [ "Handriand Excalibur" ], "owners": [ { "kind": "drive#user", "displayName": "Handriand Excalibur", "picture": { "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-H-Zbopmf3KU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAc/PZkxPa0oZ8w/s64/photo.jpg" }, "isAuthenticatedUser": false, "permissionId": "05301767890081372214", "emailAddress": "handriand@nekohime.us" } ], "lastModifyingUserName": "Handriand Excalibur", "lastModifyingUser": { "kind": "drive#user", "displayName": "Handriand Excalibur", "picture": { "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-H-Zbopmf3KU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAc/PZkxPa0oZ8w/s64/photo.jpg" }, "isAuthenticatedUser": false, "permissionId": "05301767890081372214", "emailAddress": "handriand@nekohime.us" }, "capabilities": { "canCopy": false, "canEdit": true }, "editable": true, "copyable": false, "writersCanShare": true, "shared": true, "explicitlyTrashed": false, "appDataContents": false, "headRevisionId": "0B_K_rT1g5fo7K0x5NTUraGR2VkRUOHQ0ZXlaQkhTcEErSXFzPQ", "spaces": [ "drive" ] }, { "kind": "drive#file", "id": "1pp6ydlrDn1GlHpp6iV7asOY5q5mklPMJ", "etag": "\"sUwP36qaD260RUkBRZNiE0CB3Hg/MTUxMDIxMTQ2MzMxMg\"", "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1pp6ydlrDn1GlHpp6iV7asOY5q5mklPMJ", "webContentLink": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1pp6ydlrDn1GlHpp6iV7asOY5q5mklPMJ&export=download", "alternateLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pp6ydlrDn1GlHpp6iV7asOY5q5mklPMJ/view?usp=drivesdk", "embedLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pp6ydlrDn1GlHpp6iV7asOY5q5mklPMJ/preview?usp=drivesdk", "iconLink": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/application/x-rar", "title": "Ab Du BD 480p.rar", "mimeType": "application/x-rar", "labels": { "starred": false, "hidden": false, "trashed": false, "restricted": false, "viewed": false }, "copyRequiresWriterPermission": false, "createdDate": "2017-11-09T07:10:47.865Z", "modifiedDate": "2017-11-09T07:11:03.312Z", "markedViewedByMeDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "version": "19", "parents": [ { "kind": "drive#parentReference", "id": "1kbHKqYhX9ZjWjAjE-9viiZ7AsL5HJVIO", "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1pp6ydlrDn1GlHpp6iV7asOY5q5mklPMJ/parents/1kbHKqYhX9ZjWjAjE-9viiZ7AsL5HJVIO", "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1kbHKqYhX9ZjWjAjE-9viiZ7AsL5HJVIO", "isRoot": false } ], "downloadUrl": "https://doc-0s-a4-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/o7l0aeqi0drljltr83c3565k9441n6of/nirvirens1boiduikeggb5dfon0d09e0/1549094400000/05301767890081372214/13058876669334088843/1pp6ydlrDn1GlHpp6iV7asOY5q5mklPMJ?e=download&gd=true", "userPermission": { "kind": "drive#permission", "etag": "\"sUwP36qaD260RUkBRZNiE0CB3Hg/A25TTqDBXh9qHAVoQR0peuvGl6w\"", "id": "me", "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1pp6ydlrDn1GlHpp6iV7asOY5q5mklPMJ/permissions/me", "role": "writer", "type": "user" }, "originalFilename": "Salinan [Drivenime] Ab Du BD 480p.rar", "fileExtension": "rar", "md5Checksum": "0aa1a38cf7474c479f7941f8d31ad2b2", "fileSize": "955429275", "quotaBytesUsed": "0", "ownerNames": [ "Handriand Excalibur" ], "owners": [ { "kind": "drive#user", "displayName": "Handriand Excalibur", "picture": { "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-H-Zbopmf3KU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAc/PZkxPa0oZ8w/s64/photo.jpg" }, "isAuthenticatedUser": false, "permissionId": "05301767890081372214", "emailAddress": "handriand@nekohime.us" } ], "lastModifyingUserName": "Handriand Excalibur", "lastModifyingUser": { "kind": "drive#user", "displayName": "Handriand Excalibur", "picture": { "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-H-Zbopmf3KU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAc/PZkxPa0oZ8w/s64/photo.jpg" }, "isAuthenticatedUser": false, "permissionId": "05301767890081372214", "emailAddress": "handriand@nekohime.us" }, "capabilities": { "canCopy": false, "canEdit": true }, "editable": true, "copyable": false, "writersCanShare": true, "shared": true, "explicitlyTrashed": false, "appDataContents": false, "headRevisionId": "0B_K_rT1g5fo7VVo0MUlCMFFQcVRyTytYRXhZcWtSbTlFMzBnPQ", "spaces": [ "drive" ] } ] }
```

for full can visit https://pastebin.com/acytLfN7

this get all files inside folder on drive then i want show it in a table or any. how i parse it ? example i want take [title]-[selfLink]-[mimeType]

i already try

```
foreach($list as $f){
    echo $f[title];
    echo $f[items][title];
    echo $f[items]->title;
}
```

still cant get the value always got d"h at screen
[this the result my try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO5HF.png)

Comment: Have you tried json_decode? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with objects not arrays, you will need to loop through the items:

```
$json = '//RETURNED JSON';
$all_files = json_decode($json);

foreach($all_files->items as $files){
    echo $files->title;
    echo $files->selfLink;
    echo $files->mimeType;
}
```

Comment: very2 ty sir u save my life.